# Execute file in its native directory with shell script

Tags: shell, directory, php

I'm executing a php file from the php-cli with a shell script. One of the php files creates a file named `available_data` during the course of its execution. The problem is that the php file needs to write the file `available_data` to the same directory where the php file resides on the server /var/www/html. Instead it writes the file to the directory where the shell script resides /bin/scripts/.

Here's my script (resides in /bin/scripts/createview.sh)

```
php /var/www/html/createview_customer.php
```

I think the problem is that the php file executes in /bin/scripts. How can I get the php file to execute in /var/www/html instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your shell script to enter the php scripts directory before executing it, and then return back.

```
cur=$(pwd)
cd /var/www/html && php ./createview_customer.php
cd "$cur"
```

or better modify your php script to find its directory first and open the file in that dir

```
$dirpath = dirname(__FILE__);
$handle = fopen("$dirpath/available_data", "w");
```

Comment: A better way of doing the first method is to localize the directory change in a subshell: `(cd /var/www/html && php ./createview_customer.php)`.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but since I didn't know the context I chose not to run it in a subshell.